# Fragment onStart() and onStop() not called when switching to another tab in tabbed layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context context = HomeActivity.this;
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
       Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       mSectionsPagerAdapter = new 
       SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
       mViewPager =  findViewById(R.id.container);
       mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
       TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
       mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new 
            TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
       tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new 
            TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
    }

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0 : return new HomeFrag1();
            case 1 : return new HomeFrag2();
            case 2 : return new HomeFrag3();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
}
```

When i am switching from fragment 1 to fragment 2 the onStop method of fragment 1 is not called but it gets called when i switch from fragment 2 to fragment 3. When i switch from fragment 2 to fragment 1 the onStart is not called either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a property on `ViewPager` called `offscreenPageLimit` - that is set by default to 1, meaning that `ViewPager` will persist 1 page from either side of the current page - that's why the aforementioned lifecycle callbacks are not being invoked. If you really want to keep only one fragment in-memory you can `setOffscreenPageLimit` to 0, and that way you will get the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this article](http://www.t3hmun.com/posts/2017-01-24_Fragment-Life-Cycle-in-a-ViewPager.html):

> When the page is no longer visible **or adjacent to the visible page** the ViewPager asks the adapter to destroy it.

The above seems to explain your problem. Switching from 1->2 won't try to destroy Page 1 since it's adjacent to Page 2 which is visible. But switching 2->3 will destroy Page 1 as it's no longer adjacent to the now visible Page 3.
Similarly, switching 2->1 won't re-create Page 1 as it hasn't been destroyed previously.

I suggest you try overriding `onPause()` and `onResume()` and see if that works as you'd like.